# Deserialize a non Specified Object with Jackson Library

Tags: java, android, jackson

This relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865533/serialising-a-class-member-into-json-object) question but I want to deserialize rather than serialize

I receive a json object from the server..

One of the values in the json object can be either a string or a string array.

It is possible to get this to work by defining a Object and casting it like so.

```
@JsonProperty("integration/enabled-mime-types") public Object object;

List<String> list = (List<String>) object; 

String string = (String) object;
```

However i would like to this as List rather than an object. The code I am using is this

```
@JsonDeserialize
@JsonProperty("integration/enabled-mime-types")
public void setMimeTypes(Object object) {
    if(object instanceof List) {
        this.mimeTypesArray =  (ArrayList<String>) object;
    } else {
        this.mimeTypesArray.add((String) object);
    }
}
```

But the List is never set. How to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had another setter for the array and annotated that with @JsonIgnore. That caused the objectmapper to ignore all setters and not only the only annotated